Windows can't forward ssh connection on virtualbox
I have two machine, Windows 11 running as host and Windows 7 running as guest.
both have openssh installed with different version, ssh server running on the guest and ssh client on the host.
the problem is, the server didn't respond to the client even though the log says it's connected:
$ ssh -vvv -i .ssh/id_rsa ryuu@127.0.0.1
OpenSSH_9.9p1, OpenSSL 3.4.0 22 Oct 2024
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ahmad/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 127.0.0.1 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/ahmad/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/ahmad/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: channel_clear_timeouts: clearing
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 4 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file .ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file .ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.9
kex_exchange_identification: read: Software caused connection abort
banner exchange: Connection to 127.0.0.1 port 22: Software caused connection abort


at first, I think I misconfigure the port forwarding settings in the virtual box, because it's likely that the server didn't receive any packet in the first place, so I just assume the packet is only received by virtualbox program that do forwarding jobs and then I tried to make sure I set it up properly by turn off sshd and expose nc from msys2's openbsd-netcat package on port 22, and it works properly, the client can connect and exchange data with the server:

I think the above screenshot also eliminate the possibilities of firewall issues.
okay, maybe the openssh server only listen on the loop back interface, and when I check it with netstat, the output shows it listen on all interface (I've also tried to ensure it explicitly in the sshd_config file):

and just in case the ssh server is not work properly, I tried to connect locally via loop back interface and it works without any problem:

I eliminate "different openssh version" as possibilities of the cause, because nc program on the guest can receive server's respond while the host isn't (so I think the version isn't matter for this cases):

so, what's the actual problem and who is the culprit behind this? I definitely overlook something important, please point me in the right direction, thanks in advance.
EDIT:
I've also tried to reboot (both guest and host respectively), but it changes nothing.
EDIT 2:
testing using other IP instead of loopback, and it also works, however the host still not able to receive responds:

EDIT 3:
at this point, I'm in confusion to figure out who is actually the culprit that prevents me to connect using ssh, is it the openssh itself? but it works on the guest locally, then it is virtualbox problem? but surprisingly ncat suggest me to not blame virtualbox as it works, on the same port.

Can you verify with Wireshark that the guest VM is receiving any 'forwarded' packets from the VirtualBox internal gateway? Do the VM's firewall rules (wf.msc) allow connections to the service?

I absolutely, very, highly appreciate your comment! thanks for giving me a hint to do additional check which allow me to find the culprit: "the guest's firewall"! yes, indeed it's unexpected for me personally to think it's the main actor behind this problem. I will write an answers on how to solve the problem immediately.


TL;DR it's about firewall problem.

Many thanks to grawity's comments that shed some light on my despair of failure multiple times from trial and error (please don't compare it with Mr.Thomas Edison).
after looking around at inbound rules from wf.msc, I notice that sshd isn't there. and I just hope that something will change if I put new rules related sshd and indeed it was! the connection is not blocked anymore \o/

the step: Win+r and type wf.msc, click inbound rule, action -> new rule -> select program and choose sshd.exe from usr\bin of msys2's installation directory. -> allow the connection -> apply the rule for anything that fit your preferences -> give the rule's name -> finish.
it seems that Windows 7 is not being nice with sshd program and block it right away based on executable instead of based on port, I have no idea why Windows 7 behave this way, it not give any sign, a prompt or anything else to notify user what's going on, at least in my experience using Windows 11, by default sshd program is not blocked.
hope it helps other that encounter similar problem.
